# rigging error: object entirely pivots around joint incorrectly

Tags: rigging

I have an object frame that I want to make like a robotic arm movement for. when I add armature to it the entire object pivots around the joint instead of just one part of it like an elbow joint.
how do I fix this error?

[image]

Comment: you need to assign the mesh with automatic weights, or do it manually within the weight paint mode

Answer (score 0):

Parent the object to the armature with the *With Empty Groups* option, it will add a series of vertex groups to the object, that have the same name as the bones, but it won't assign any vertex to these vertex groups for the moment. Then switch to *Edit* mode, select the vertices you want, in the *Object Data* panel select the vertex group they should be part of and click on the *Assign* button.